# How to get Java's .readAllBytes() in Javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, arrays

I'm looking for a way to do this:

```
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("", filePath);
byte [] fileData = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

in Javascript client-side. Is it possible? I know you can do such thing server-side with, for example, Node.js but I need to implement such function using client-side Javascript.

What I am trying to achieve is to get the byte array from a file.

Comment: More information would be nice. For example, JavaScript run in browsers cannot access the filesystem at all, so it would already fail there.

Comment: You can't access the client file system except in very closely proscribed ways.

Comment: I want to access the bytes of a file in an <input type="file"/>